# How to write custom client-side jQuery validation in ASP.NET MVC 2 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I've read [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) on custom client-side validation in ASP.NET MVC 2.  I want to do the same thing but with the jQuery adapter and using ASP.NET MVC 2 RC (as opposed to MVC 2 Beta that the post uses).  Has anyone been able to figure how to do this?

I specially want to implement the password matching validation (i.e. password & confirm password must match). The ASP.NET MVC 2 RC VS.NET project template does show how to implement that on the server-side (using the `PropertiesMustMatchAttribute`) but not on the client-side.

Comment: There are sort of two questions here:
1) How do you do model-level validation on the client side?
2) How do you execute that validation using jQuery?

They're both interesting questions. You may want to update the question title to incorporate that. (I'm interested in the answer to #1 but accidentally happened upon this question.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you already followed Phil Haack's instructions here http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) on how to get custom validation working with MS AJAX client validation.  To get it to work with jQuery, you'll need to modify the MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js file:

- In the __MVC_CreateRulesForField(validationField) function, you'll need to add a case statement.  Continuing Phil's example, you'll need to add:

  case "price":

  __MVC_ApplyValidator_Price(rulesObj, thisRule.ValidationParameters["min"]);

  break;
- You'll then need to create the __MVC_ApplyValidator_Price function:

function __MVC_ApplyValidator_Price(object, value) {

```
// min is what jQuery Validate uses to validate for minimum values
object["min"] = value;
```

}

That should be enough to get Phil's example working.

Now, regarding your PropertiesMustMatchAttribute validation, it doesn't look like MVC generates the client-side json validation definition for attributes that decorate classes.  Since PropertiesMustMatchAttribute must be used on the model (and not the property), I can't figure out how to make it trigger client-side validation.  Instead, I took a different approach.  I created a dummy validation attribute who's IsValid() overload always returns true, and used this attribute on a property.  This is just a dummy attribute that will delegate the validation logic to jQuery validator's equalTo function.  Here's the dummy attribute:

```
public class PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string MatchProperty { get; set; }

    public PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerAttribute(string matchProperty)
    {
        MatchProperty = matchProperty;
        ErrorMessage = "{0} doesn't match {1}.";
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, MatchProperty);
    }
}
```

Here is the custom validator:

```
public class PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerAttribute>
{
    private string _message;
    private string _matchProperty;

    public PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerValidator(ModelMetadata metaData, ControllerContext context, PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerAttribute attribute)
        : base(metaData, context, attribute)
    {
        _message = attribute.FormatErrorMessage(metaData.DisplayName);
        _matchProperty = attribute.MatchProperty;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = _message,
            ValidationType = "equalTo"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("matchField", _matchProperty);

        return new[] { rule };
    }
}
```

the above custom validator needs to be registered in Application_Start() per Phil's blog:

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerAttribute), typeof(PropertiesMustMatchClientTriggerValidator));

Finally, you need to modify the MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js file:

- Add the following case statement to __MVC_CreateRulesForField:

case "equalTo":

__MVC_ApplyValidator_EqualTo(rulesObj, thisRule.ValidationParameters["matchField"]);

break;

- add this function:

function __MVC_ApplyValidator_EqualTo(object, elemId) {

```
object["equalTo"] = document.getElementById(elemId);
```

}

Now you need to attach the dummy validation attribute to a property:

```
    [PropertiesMustMatchClientTrigger("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

That should do it.

Creating this dummy attribute is a bit ugly, so I hope someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer.  I'll try that and update the result later.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up on this. Based on Brad Wilson's talk on C4MVC (http://www.viddler.com/explore/c4mvc/videos/24/), the MVC team is considering implementing client-side validation for model-level annotations in MVC 3.  If they do that, this type of problem will be much easier to solve.

Comment: Finally I tried your solution and it works like charm.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to add a custom jQuery validation:

```
$.validator.addMethod("noSpaces", function(value, element) {
    if ($(element).val().indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Value must not contain spaces");
```

Comment: How can you integrate that custom method to the ASP.NET MVC 2's validation engine?

Comment: Based on Phil's post, the name alone should do it. But I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, and you are/were using MVC2, but MVC3 now comes with the CompareAttribute, which can be used for your use case of password confirmation matching.

Source: http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/asp-net-mvc-3-data-annotations-provide-property-level-contingent-validation/